# CSS3 Menu Border - RightArrow Effect

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to achieve the right arrow effect using css3, i tried a bunch of times already but no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/ffCDw/

```
.menu li {
list-style-type: none;
display:inline;

}
.menu li a {
padding: 0 20px;
background: green;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? Maybe provide an example image of how it should look?

Comment: A right facing arrow? You haven't included any CSS for this

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the approach with the borders wasn't quite satisfying enough for me, especially if you want to use :hover...

**HTML**

I put a span inside the div, this is for the arrow only.

```
<div class="arrow">
    I am the first arrow
    <span></span>
<div>
```

**CSS**

span get's position:absolute;

[image: div and span]

Here the span:after is positioned and transformed (-45deg), so it points to the right.

[image: span:after]

And finally, by putting span overflow:hidden, there is only the part left visible that points to the right...

[image: after setting span overflow:hidden]

```
span {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -1.625em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -1em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background: #60bee7;
}
```

I hope this is understandable. The only thing left is to style your *div* and *span:after* and if you want define the :hover states aswell on these elements.

Please note not to give the *span* any background-color

And here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/marczking/PyKFT/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an arrow to the right edge of these elements:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffCDw/2/)

We're using CSS to add a triangle element after your anchor tag with this block:

```
.menu li a:after{
    height:0;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: solid 5px green;
    border-top: solid 9px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 9px transparent;
}
```

And then increasing the left margin of your `li` elements to account for the additional space these take up.  You can play with the length of the triangle by increasing the pixel size of the `border-left` property, but be sure to increase the margin of the `li` accordingly.

Comment: Nice technique to create triangle! +1