# Div as arrow shape without using other elements inside

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to shape a div like an arrow ?

I saw this allready but in the most pages it was build with several divs and I simply want to use one.

Shape should look like

```
 ______________
|              \
|______________/
```

I tried around a lil bit with [some samples](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) but I could not get it to be in the shape I want. And as you can see, there are way more difficult shapes that can be build.

Anyone knows how to achive this ?

Comment: rectangle + triangle right

Comment: or maybe you like this http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: you can also see my previous answer if that might help ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298723/css3-menu-border-rightarrow-effect/15302449#15302449

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gotcha. (After some work)

```css
.block:after {
  color: black;
  border-left: 13px solid;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -13px;
}
.block {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Stole some of this from Tom Toms; didn't know you could do tricks like that with the border. You might also be able to have adjustable sizes using font-size: (basesize) and using `em`s for the other sizes.

Comment: that looks like that what i want to have :D thank you very much.. now I have to try to get this on my li instead of div than everything is fine :D

Comment: what do you mean with transition ?

Comment: Look up the transition property on your preferred CSS reference site (my favorite: developer.mozilla.org ) . It basically specifies: "When this CSS property changes from one number to another, gradually change that number across all intermediate values based on a certain time value".It's one of CSS's two forms of animation, and generally fits UI interactions better.

Answer (score 1):

You need two `div` elements a rectangle one and a triangle one, no way around that except a background image as far as I know. Here is how to get a triangle pointing to the right:

```
.triangle {
  color: black;
  border-left: 13px solid;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
```

Any specific reason you want to use only one `div` ?

Comment: Yes because its actualy a `li` and the "arrow" should be displayed on hover. So actually the li background is the arrow. In this case I can only use one ^^

Comment: If you decide to use my example, you could try putting a transition property on the "right" attribute, so that it goes from 0 to -13px during the hover. It might be a simple way of making it a bit smoother.

Comment: What I do is add an absolute span inside the li that will be the triangle. The li element is the rectangle and has background & color defined that switch on hover. As the span is a child its color will change too so no need for javascript.